# Angular velocities of a spinning top

Tags: angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics, angular-velocity

[image: Pages from *An elementary treatment of the theory of spinning tops and gyroscopic motion*]

Can someone please explain the concept of azimuthal plane, azimuthal velocity,etc. I have never seen this term before, "azimuthal". However, when I first saw it I thought :"ok, this is a plane that passes through the axle of the spinning top and acompanies it around its precession therefore having angular velocity $\Omega$ around some vertical axis. The spinning top also possesses this angular velocity around a vertical axis."

Take in consideration that $\dot{\psi}$ is the same as $\Omega$ (different notations as it were different main topics on the book, but not important for my question)

And I also understand (I think) the projections of this velocity (even though they are not intuitive, for example the $\Omega$ component on $GA$ of the spinning top, but still).

But then at the page on the right of the atached image, at the highlighted part, they are using the conservation of momentum around $OZ$, however they use a double projection of $\Omega$ to the vertical axis. Why not use the $\Omega$ only, as it is already on the vertical axis OZ?.

Comment: You've got too many questions in one. I recommend you to read about "Euler's angles".

Comment: Ok, I'll look into it, I kind of dove into this topic due to my curiosity but I feel that I am missing some pillars, anyway thank you